# How to select just the foreign key value using Criteria Query?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Suppose I have two entities as:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b; 

    //more attributes
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    private int id;
}
```

So, the table for A is having a column as `b_id` as the foreign key.

Now, I want to select just the `b_id` based on some criteria on other fields. How can I do this using criteria query?

I tried doing following which throws IllegalArgumentException saying `"Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [b_id] on this ManagedType [A]"`

```
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Integer.class);
    Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
    Path<Integer> bId = root.get("b_id");
    //building the criteria
    criteriaQuery.select(bId);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join to `B` and then fetch the `id`:

```
Path<Integer> bId = root.join("b").get("id");
```

Comment: why is it necessary to join B when the info is present in A itself?

Comment: Well this is not selecting "just the fk" but it is doing a join... Agreed with @msfk why is the join needed? How should one just grab the fk field and use that in the criteria?

Comment: How to use in clause on column B without join . i.e just passing ids in "in" clause in criteria api

Comment: A join of `B` is **not** necessary if you want to filter only by the foreign key. You can do `criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("b").get("id"), <idOfB>)`.

Comment: See the answer of David Windrem for a solution that does not use a table join

Answer (score 6):

You can declare the foreign key in class A where "B_ID" is the name of the foreign key column in table A.  And then you can root.get("bId") in your criteriabuilder example above.
I have the same problem as you and this is working for me.

```
@Column(name="B_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int bId;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
private B b;
```

Comment: @AnmolGupta could you please update the accepted answer. This solution prevents a table join, which should make the query way faster

Answer (score 2):

As correctly pointed out by @T3rm1 above:

> A join of B is not necessary if you want to filter only by the foreign key. You can do `criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("b").get("id"), <idOfB>)`.

Basically, the `root.get` will get an expression to the mapped object in the model. You can therefore do a nested `get` on the foreign key. In summary:

```
root.get("b").get("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to join if you're evaluating the FK primary key in the query, that is present in the A entity.

```
root.get("b")
```

This code will retrieve the FK by its primary key.
For example you can do:

```
root.get("b").in(List.of(1,2,3,4));
```

And you have a valid predicate that is comparing the FK value with this list.