# Hibernate - How to select just the foreign key value using Criteria Query without doing a Join?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

So there is this similar (almost identical) question: [How to select just the foreign key value using Criteria Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450072/how-to-select-just-the-foreign-key-value-using-criteria-query)  but **I need to avoid doing the join**.

So I have two tables, one with a FK to the other

(Service)

- id
- name
- account_id

(Account)

- id
- name

Service class has the FK defined this way:

```java
@Entity
public class Service extends BaseDbEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Account account;

...
```

and what I want to do is query all the Service's that correspond to a given account, having the accountId, without doing a JOIN, because the id is already in the Service table.

Now, my criteria query looks like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Service> criteria = cb.createQuery(Service.class);
Root<Service> root = criteria.from(Service.class);
criteria
        .select(root)
        .where(cb.equal(root.join("account").get("id"), accountId));
session.createQuery(criteria).getResultStream();
```

This ends up generating this query:

`Hibernate: select service0_.id as id1_3_, service0_.name as name4_3_, service0_.account_id as account_id6_3_ from Service service0_ inner join Account account1_ on service0_.account_id=account1_.id where account1_.id=?`

Which doesn't make sense.. it does a join on a field and then just creates a where clause for that field.

If I do:

```java
root.get("account_id")
```

it just throws an exception saying the field is not available.

What is the correct way to avoid this?

Comment: Then you need to add a field in entity for `account_id` and join column with the field [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58690889/4207306)  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just found the answer to my question:

Instead of doing

```java
root.join("account").get("id")
```

I just needed to do:

```java
root.get("account").get("id")
```

which avoids performing the JOIN.

Comment: Did you check the query it's not joining for query ?

Comment: Yes, the query log now says this: `Hibernate: select service0_.id as id1_3_, service0_.name as name4_3_, service0_.owner_id as owner_id6_3_, from Service service0_ where service0_.owner_id=?`

Comment: `owner_id` means `account_id` right ? Good to know :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was doing some changes, it's the account_id